# How could landline telephone service cause fire alarms to activate?

Tags: telephone

Someone I know informed me that their home’s fire alarm is occasionally triggered when he uses his home phone (landline). His alarm system company stated that they do not know why this occurs. They believe that it could be caused by short waves emitted by the telephone. Any idea as to how this could happen?

Comment: you provided incomplete information .... your post says nothing about the telephone that is being used on the landline ... it also says nothing about the alarm system

Comment: What kind of fire alarm? Some fire alarm systems are wired back to central control box, many times in combination with a security system. Many of these systems can also dial the fire department when an alarm triggers the same way they dial the security monitoring company. They do this over the telephone line. It's possible that there is a short somewhere (likely in the control box) that the telephone line triggers somehow. Need more detail but that's my suspicion.

Comment: Sorry about that. I’ll ask that person for more clarification the next him I talk to him.

Comment: Ring tone is pretty high voltage (but should be balanced). Is the phone cable anywhere near the alarm cables?

Comment: Is it the actual fire alarm that is triggered, or is the alarm company receiving calls from the setup? Normally, when the fire alarm is actuated, it grabs the land line away from any telsets, then it dials the alarm company.